# Kubernetes can telnet into POD but can't curl web content

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

In my Kubernetes environment I have following to pods running

```
NAME                                           READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP             NODE
httpd-6cc5cff4f6-5j2p2                         1/1       Running   0          1h        172.16.44.12   node01
tomcat-68ccbb7d9d-c2n5m                        1/1       Running   0          45m       172.16.44.13   node02
```

One is a Tomcat instance and other one is a Apache instance.

from `node01` and `node02` I can curl the httpd which is using port `80`. But If i curl the tomcat server which is running on `node2` from `node1` it fails. I get below output.

```
[root@node1~]# curl -v 172.16.44.13:8080
* About to connect() to 172.16.44.13 port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 172.16.44.13...
* Connected to 172.16.44.13 (172.16.44.13) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 172.16.44.13:8080
> Accept: */*
>
^C
[root@node1~]# wget -v 172.16.44.13:8080
--2019-01-16 12:00:21--  http://172.16.44.13:8080/
Connecting to 172.16.44.13:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

But I'm able telnet to port `8080` on `172.16.44.13` from `node1`

```
[root@node1~]# telnet 172.16.44.13 8080
Trying 172.16.44.13...
Connected to 172.16.44.13.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet>
```

Any reason for this behavior? why am I able to telnet but unable to get the web content? I have also tried different ports but curl is working only for port 80.

Comment: can you check the tomcat port with `kubectl describe pod tomcat-68ccbb7d9d-c2n5m`

Comment: @edbighead- I was able to get this fixed by disabling selinux on my nodes.

Comment: @edbighead -  I was able to get this fixed by disabling selinux on my nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this fixed by disabling `selinux` on my nodes.